# Sending request with a language selection redirect back to the main request site like facebook not back to the application in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect, url-routing

I made a Laravel application with the language switch.
that after a language change the app redirect you back after the language change on the site.
the code is as follow:

```
public function lang($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

But i got the problem if someone send the link on facebook or other social media as example
[www.example.com/lang/en](http://www.example.com/lang/en) than the application redirect me back to the facebook but not the main application.

I was searching around how to do this better but always i saw hard coded things like extra URL as example
[www.example.com/lang/change/en](http://www.example.com/lang/change/en) with another function.

But i think tehere should be a way to do this better with an if checking the request but actually i can check the request url but i get always the app url back and nothing more.

So my question is how can i made so that if someone enter te url from other site than the application is will redirect me to the [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/) (With the langage from the sended request like [www.example.com/lang/en](http://www.example.com/lang/en) and not back to the facebook or like that) and when it happens on the application site will return me back to the previuse site where i was like [www.example.com/post/3](http://www.example.com/post/3)

I'm a starter after the school so do not be mad that i do not know everthing
If someone can help me i would be thankfull!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a possibility, do that with javascript or vue, and then just reload the window location.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-lang="es" class="lang">Español</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-lang="en" class="lang">English</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-lang="it" class="lang">Italiano</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click",".lang", function () {
    $.get('/lang/' + $(this).data('lang')).then((res) => {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

EDIT: For extra clarity, this is your lang function, you don't need to return a redirect.

```
public function lang($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return response()->json('ok');
}
```

Comment: I tried this allready option but didn't work i was still redirecting back to the facebook

Comment: For extra clarity, I added the lang() function. You don't need to redirect there.

Comment: Okay but i have more languages English was Just an example

Comment: Added html and function with parameters for clarity

Comment: I'm still redirecting back to facebook but then i get only ok in the fb url

Comment: Check if you have a form that is being submitted.  With javascript:void() you should not be getting a redirection.  Did you remove the return redirect()->back()  from the php side?

Comment: Yes i didt it allready and i do not know why is this happening there :/